# Why samba can not grant access on some directories?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have a server with samba installed. I need to share some directories under the /var/spool path. But I faced with strange trouble: I can not get access to /var/spool with samba.

There is /etc/smb.conf (I have shared "/" for testing purposes. I had "/var/spool/asterisk/monitor" there earlier):

```
############SMB.CONF##############
[global]
workgroup = DOMAIN
server string = DPM
netbios name = DPM
netbios aliases = fileserver
security = user
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
encrypt passwords = yes
map to guest = bad user
hosts allow = 192.168.1.10
load printers = no
disable spoolss = yes
local master = no
unix charset = utf-8
dos charset = cp866
unix extensions = No
wide links = Yes
follow symlinks = Yes

[recordings]
  path = /
  writeable = no
  guest ok = yes
  browseable = yes
```

I **have** access to `/var` and `/home/asterisk_recordings` from the samba share.

but I **have no** access to `/asterisk_recordings` and `/var/spool`

This is their `stat` output:

```
[root@mistral home]# stat /asterisk_recordings/
  File: «/asterisk_recordings/»
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   каталог
Device: 902h/2306d      Inode: 44564481    Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  498/asterisk)   Gid: (  498/asterisk)
Access: 2016-10-15 04:07:42.351252721 +0700
Modify: 2016-10-15 04:08:13.475252709 +0700
Change: 2016-10-15 04:26:09.004783795 +0700

[root@mistral home]# stat /home/asterisk-recordings/
  File: «/home/asterisk-recordings/»
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   каталог
Device: 902h/2306d      Inode: 11796594    Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  498/asterisk)   Gid: (  498/asterisk)
Access: 2016-10-15 04:25:21.600783813 +0700
Modify: 2016-10-15 03:28:01.698832140 +0700
Change: 2016-10-15 04:02:58.235252829 +0700

[root@mistral home]# stat /var
  File: «/var»
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   каталог
Device: 902h/2306d      Inode: 38797313    Links: 18
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-10-14 22:17:06.070466036 +0700
Modify: 2016-10-02 20:33:45.489395585 +0700
Change: 2016-10-02 20:33:45.489395585 +0700

[root@mistral home]# stat /var/spool
  File: «/var/spool»
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   каталог
Device: 902h/2306d      Inode: 38797581    Links: 10
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-10-15 02:15:24.569158693 +0700
Modify: 2016-10-15 00:26:50.642447066 +0700
Change: 2016-10-15 00:47:54.304488080 +0700
```

What could be a wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, SELinux settings were the reason.

`setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro 1` solved my problem.